# Onclick of button empty the WordPress editor content

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to empty the content of WordPress wysiwyg editor on click of a button.
I have a simple button **delete**. So when I click that button, the editor with **id="editor1"** contents should become empty.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `$("#editor1").html("");` ??

Comment: `$("#editor1").empty();` should work as well.

Comment: can you provide what wysiwyg editor's DOM is? maybe something like $("#editor1").find('textarea').html("");